# Benefits of library versus a plain contract (upgradeability)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, library

I'm trying to find what the benefit is of a library. I found the following statements. (Please correct me if i'm wrong)

- Cost less gas to deploy
- Uses the storage of the calling contract
- the library and contract are compiled separately but the library gets linked into the contract as a part of it when deploying.

The major downside I see of a library is that it's a part of the contract. Meaning if I want to update the library I need to redeployed I also need to redeployed the linked contract. If the library was just a plain contract I only need to redeploy that contract and set the reference again to the other contract.

```
contract Lib {
    //Some code
}

contract A {

    Lib someLib;

    function setLibReference(address libAddress) public {
        someLib = Lib(libAddress);
    }
}
```

For me this seems as a major downside or am I wrong in this?